# Answer prompts automatically in a shell script during an installation

Tags: scripts

I am running an installation script which I need to answer the following prompts
`{o 3 n enter u n}` to achieve the outcome that I want.

Below is what I wrote in the script, but it seem not to be working,

```
echo "o 3 N Enter U N" | ./$new_upgrd
```

Comment: Is one of the required inputs literally the string `enter` - or does this indicate a press of the "Enter" key?

Comment: It indicate press of the "Enter" key.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have newlines between the strings:

```
printf '%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n' o 3 N Enter U N | ./$new_upgrd
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. You mean this?                                                                                                                                               
  printf '%o\n%3\n%N\n%enter\n%U\n%N\n' | ./$new_upgrd

Comment: No. %s is a placeholder for string from argument. So it should exactly be as I wrote. Try the part up to the pipe to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have newlines between the strings:

```
echo -e "o\n3\nN\nenter\nU\nN" | ./$new_upgrd
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work as desired.